# Mat to vector<Point3f>

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I have a vector of vector and I want to take values from matrix type MAT and assign these values to it.
I am using eclipse and I am trying to push back on the vector like that

```
vector<Point3f> output;
output.push_back(Point3f(Transformed_world_coordinates.at<Point3f>(0, 0)));
output.push_back(Point3f(Transformed_world_coordinates.at<Point3f>(1, 0)));
```

the problem is when I run , I get really high values in most of the vector, sth like 7.47385e+027 which is totally not what I am trying to assign 
I checked the output of the matrix right before I use the previous code and the numbers are in the way I want(ex:0.02345458)

Comment: note: Keep in mind that Transformed_world_coordinate is the matrix that I mentioned. I am trying to assign the first row of the matrix to the first vector element and the second row of the matrix to the second element

Comment: You can edit your own question, rather than commenting on it.

Comment: What's the datatype of the elements in and the number of channels in `Transformed_world_coordinates`.

Comment: data type is float

Comment: Those weird numbers means either your matrix is not initialized with values or you access its pixels incorrectly. What is the type, size and number of channels of Transformed_world_coordinate?